# make web-browser application in j2me?

Tags: java-me, browser, mobile-application

I'm new in j2me,but my recent craze in mobile application,I started from some basic application,I have read j2me complete reference book,I have run my small j2me programs on my cellphone,now I want to make web browser for my cellphone,can you suggest me some examples that will help me making this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `LWUIT` there is [`HTMLComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/bbjidhgf.html).

The most simple use case of HTMLComponent is rendering rich text:

```
HTMLComponent htmlC = new HTMLComponent(null);
htmlC.setBodyText("Hello <b>bold text</b>");
```